# URL: How to make get parameters looks like directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

This request:

```
http://domain.com/newest
```

should be rewritten to:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?list=newest
```

I tried to achieve that redirection with `.htaccess` and arrived at this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?list=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But that still doesn't seem to work. How do I get this rewrite and redirection to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `RewriteRule` condition in this way:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?list=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then, in our script, you can access to rewritten rule through `$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]`, whereas the original request is available as usual through `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`.

Note that - if your intention is to remap all ‘Not Found’ incoming requests, you can also simply use this rule:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

and then, at the top of `index.php` file, process the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and assign the proper value to `$list` variable.

So, i.e., having URL http://domain.com/newest:

```
$list = substr( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'], 1 );
```

`$list` will assume `newest` as value.